# time spent actuals

Tags: rally

I would like to be able to copy the total "Time Spent" from a Task on the Time sheet to the Task "Actual" field. This way I can use the Time Sheet to enter the time I've spent on a task and see the value (in the form of the "Actual" column) on the Team Status page. Suggestions the best way to tackle this? I'm new to the Rally APIs so not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The Time Spent field only exists on the Task Detail Page. It is not actually stored in the on the object and thus not returned in the WSAPI. If you wanted to update the Actual value for a task you would have to sum up the hours field on the [TimeEntryValue](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#TimeEntryValue).

My recommendation would be to use a fetch that looks something like

```
fetch="Hours,TimeEntryItem,Task"
```

That would give you everything you need in one query.