# How can i use the Rally APIs for Java to get the time spent for the tasks ? Please advise

Tags: rally

How can i use the Rally APIs for Java to get the time spent for the tasks ?
I tried the Tasks query request but does not work

Comment: Which Java API are you using, REST or SOAP? As for the structure of the query - you'll want to query on TimeEntryItem - see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543256/time-spent-actuals for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The query results will only contain minimal info, so you need to perform a read. Loop through the results set and do a full read on each object

```
tasks[i] = (Task)service.read(tasks[i]);
```

Then you will have access to all attributes